# Adminer-Edit calendar plugin

Tags: php, mysql, adminer

I want to add edit calendar plugin to my adminer, I followed all the steps that have been given on the adminer.org but when I refresh my local adminer URL it doesn't show any change however it should have shown a calender in a date field, pleas help?

Comment: The given information is not sufficient to answer. Please provide more details like how you are trying to debug it, what error you are getting, and so on.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.